# Bash Scripts- File path validation, file name match and show rows in file

Tags: bash

So I have a task where I have to "ask a user to provide a path" within the path there has to be a specific file. If not, I need to terminate the script. if the file is there, i then need to verify if the file contains no more than 20 rows. If it doesn't, then I need to terminate the script.

I do have this at the moment.

```
echo "Please provide a path to the url_list file:"
read filepath

if [[ -d "$filepath" ]] && [[ ! -f *url_list* ]]; then
  echo "Path and file has been found"
else
  echo "Error: ${filepath} not found. Can not continue."
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm thinking I need a while loop potentially. But I'm a bit lost.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear to me the purpose of the test `[[ ! -f *url_list* ]]`

Comment: Iim trying to validate a path for the file present within the specified path. So for example if the path was "/home/local/USERS/xiMoshyx" i though the file url_list would verify it? does this make sense?

Comment: Is `url_list` a filename and do you want to check if the `"$filepath/url_list"` exists? Then why not `[[ -f "$filepath/url_list" ]]` ?

Comment: yes url list is file name. But you need to specific the path that it exists in

Answer (score 0):

The command `wc` from `coreutils` can print the number of lines in a file
Unfortunately `wc` prints also the file name so you need to remove that.

```
if [ $(wc -l url_list | cut -f1 -d' ') -gt 20 ]; then
   echo "Error: ${filepath}/url_list has more than 20 entries. Can not continue."
   exit 1
fi
```

Notes:

- `wc -l` - print number of lines
- `cut -f1 -d' '` - print just the first(1) field separated by ' '(space)
- `-gt` - greater than